# FireFox with ActiveX

Tags: firefox, activex, browser-plugin

I saw a ActiveX plugin for FireFox [here](http://code.google.com/p/ff-activex-host/)

I'm trying to use a Bematech printer in FireFox, using this following `<OBJECT>` tag, that works fine in Internet Explorer

`<object id="BemaPrinter1" height="14" width="14" classid="clsid:310DBDAC-85FF-4008-82A8-E22A09F9460B" VIEWASTEXT></OBJECT>`

In FireFox don't print and don't show any message.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That plugin has some documentation, feel free to read it. Indeed, on the very first page it says (under Security):

> The plugin has some security related features to limit the risk it
>   might pose to users by making ActiveX controls available in Firefox.
>   First of all, it is using a special MIME Type so that it won't get
>   triggered by sites that were not specifically designed for it.
>   Additionally, it supports lists of well known CLSIDs and PROGIDs so
>   that it can be limited to use with specific controls and interfaces.
>   Finally, it can be "site locked" to make sure it's only being used by
>   a predetermined list of domains.

The first condition means that you need a `TYPE="application/x-itst-activex"` attribute on your `<object>` tag. The other two security features are optional even though I would consider them highly recommendable - they have to be enabled by [changing the source code of the plugin and recompiling it](http://code.google.com/p/ff-activex-host/wiki/Documentation#Preparing_the_Plugin_for_Distribution). So as long as you are using the vanilla build adding the correct `type` attribute should be sufficient.